# How can I correctly use the scroll event listener in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the scroll event on my navbar correctly. I am trying to use the scroll event to remove the first Navbar and get the image to display along with the second navbar once the user scrolls on the page. I was able to achieve the scroll effect for the first one but when you scroll it shows the first navbar albeit slightly. You have to scroll really fast to see it. [image]

This is my JSX code

```
class header extends Component {
  state={
    showNav: true
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
   } 
  handleScroll = e => {
    const doesShowNavigation = this.state.showNav;
    if(window.scrollY > 50){
      this.setState({showNav: !doesShowNavigation})
    }   
  }
  render(){ 
  return (
     <div className={styles.Header}>
       <div>
           { this.state.showNav ?
             <FirstHeader onScroll={this.handleScroll}/>
            : null}

           <SecondHeader/>
       </div>
     </div> 
    
  )
}
}
```

Code for the First Header JSX

```
const firstHeader = (props)=>{
  return(
    <div className={styles.FirstHeaderContainer} onScroll={props.onScroll}>
      <div>
        <div>
         <img src={Logo} alt="logo"/>
         <h1>DODO PIZZA</h1>
         <p>Fresh Delivery in Lagos</p>
         </div>
         <div>
           <h3>Call to order</h3>
           <h1>+234 812 106 9256</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div>
         <button>Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  )
}
```

Code for the Second header JSX

```
const secondHeader = (props) => {
  return (
  <div className={styles.secondHeaderContainer}>
    <div>
     <ul>
      <li>Pizza</li>
      <li>Sides</li>
      <li>Desserts</li>
      <li>Drinks</li>
      <li>Deals</li>
      <li>Pizza Builder</li>
     </ul>
    </div>  
    <div>
      <button>My Orders</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try to use `this.setState({showNav: false})`.

Comment: Thanks I just tried it and it works but when I return back to the top of the page, the oldNavbar doesnt show.

Comment: I see, in that case, you probably need something like `this.setState({showNav: (window.scrollY < 50)})` and get rid of the `if` condition.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel so stupid right now. I am so grateful.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, good luck.

Comment: One more thing, If I wanted to add the logo to the second Navbar and make it appear on scroll, do I need to change the second Nav component to a class based one?

Comment: No, you can pass the `showNav` as a property (`<SecondHeader showLogo={!showNav} />`) and, in the component use something like `{props.showLogo ? <img src={Logo} alt="logo"/> : ""}`